# HAProxy multiple health check types on one backend

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to have a `httpchk` on port 8008 and `ssl-hello-chk`on port 5432 in a single haproxy tcp backend? From what I can see health checks are defined with `option` and then by adding `check` to the server definition which leads me to believe that only one health check may be done per backend.

Am I wrong and is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the same server twice within the backend and set one of each health check.